# Active Directory Win2k19 DNS record refused

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, samba4

I am migrating a Samba domain to AD on Windows 2k19.  The domain successfully replicated, and I transferred 5 of the 7 Samba FSMOs (there are 2 additional FSMOs that Samba claimed that Active Directory documentation does not reference). The DNS zone was replicated successfully, and up until just recently I was able to add/edit records on the new server.  However, I just started experiencing an issue where I can no longer add A records, or even create a new zone - every action I attempt results in "refused."

I am able to add/edit records on the old Samba server, which successfully replicate to the new server.  I can also delete records on the new server, which successfully replicate to the Samba server.

Researching the issue, I found a suggestion to make a change to a group policy item, but that did not seem to help, and I haven't found any errors in the Event Log that would seem to point me to what the problem is.

Comment: What is the Zone type?

Comment: @GregAskew I'm not really sure TBH.  There is the zone that Samba set up during it's initial setup process, and some other zones were added later, all were integrated with AD.  They were all replicated when I stood up the new windows DC.

I did find a solution/workaround, I posted the link below.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2093484-linux-samba-to-windows-ad-2008-r2-dns-problem

Use ASDI Edit:
Connect to and expand the "Configuration" context, then select CN=Partitions.
Edit each crossRef listed, and set the msDS-SDReferenceDomain attribute to the DN of the domain "DC=...,DC=..."